# `sudo startx` works but `startx` gives low-res screen, no Dash

Tags: 14.04, software-installation, intel-graphics

After a recent system upgrade, I found I could not login and get my normal screen. The screen I got after typing my password was low-resolution, had no Dash and <kbd>Ctrl-Alt-T</kbd> did not open a terminal. `lshw -C display` shows:

```
*-display
   description: VGA compatible controller
   product: 82G33/G31 Express Integrated Graphics Controller
```

I found that, logging in with <kbd>Ctrl-Alt-F1</kbd>, I got the same results with `/usr/bin/startx`, but `sudo /usr/bin/startx` gave me my normal screen (but I was logged in as `root`).

Comment: What's interesting is that you're trying to `startx` as user, while all files in `/etc/X11/xinit/` directory are root owned (which is right, they should be root-owned).

Comment: Does this also happen in the guest session???

Comment: can you adjust the resolution of the low res screen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLVED by simply removing the `fglrx` driver (with the driver's directions, not just `sudo rm`), and depending on Ubuntu's built-in driver. `fglrx` is for advanced graphics cards, and I have an old one.

Answer (score 2):

Update 2015Mar12-2238: NOT SOLVED! I'm still struggling.

Original (non-)answer:

Since `startx` works for `root` and fails for `user`, it is a permission problem.

To answer the question. "In all my installed software, what can `root` execute that `user` cannot?", I first collected the data with:

```
#!/bin/bash
#
for pkg in $( dpkg -l | egrep '^ii' | awk '{print $2 }' ) ; do
    echo "$(date '+%F %T') $pkg" >&2
    dpkg -L "$pkg" | \
        sed -e 's/^.*to: //' | \
        while read phile ; do
            sudo /usr/bin/stat  \  
                --printf="=%a,%A %u:%g Chgd: %z = %Z %N\n" ":$clean" | \
                tr -d '‘’'
        done
done  > plan.out
```

Then, via `egrep '^=...,[dr]..x.....-' plan.out | sort -n -k8 | uniq` I saw (truncated for space, only "recent" changes):

```
=700,drwx------ 101:4 Chgd: 2015-01-30 19:11:24.363915087 -0500 = 1422663084 ‘/var/spool/rsyslog’
=700,drwx------ 0:0 Chgd: 2015-01-31 11:21:44.664379962 -0500 = 1422721304 ‘/var/lib/libvirt/sanlock’
=700,drwx------ 0:0 Chgd: 2015-02-22 12:25:22.314994852 -0500 = 1424625922 ‘/root’
=700,drwx------ 0:0 Chgd: 2015-02-23 11:40:00.909677880 -0500 = 1424709600 ‘/var/lib/polkit-1’
=700,drwx------ 0:0 Chgd: 2015-02-23 11:40:00.917677856 -0500 = 1424709600 ‘/etc/polkit-1/localauthority’
=700,drwx------ 154:161 Chgd: 2015-02-24 16:06:58.612884945 -0500 = 1424812018 ‘/var/run/gdm/greeter’
=750,drwxr-x--- 144:128 Chgd: 2015-02-24 16:07:01.015677190 -0500 = 1424812021 ‘/var/cache/libvirt/qemu’
=750,drwxr-x--- 154:161 Chgd: 2015-02-24 16:07:19.838216115 -0500 = 1424812039 ‘/var/lib/gdm’
=700,drwx------ 0:0 Chgd: 2015-02-24 16:07:38.480845470 -0500 = 1424812058 ‘/var/lib/sudo’
=750,drwxr-x--- 144:128 Chgd: 2015-02-24 16:07:45.033551778 -0500 = 1424812065 ‘/var/lib/libvirt/qemu’
=750,drwxr-x--- 134:4 Chgd: 2015-02-25 07:57:51.259376791 -0500 = 1424869071 ‘/var/log/glance’
=750,drwxr-x--- 33:4 Chgd: 2015-02-26 08:08:02.006782269 -0500 = 1424956082 ‘/var/log/nginx’
=750,drwxr-x--- 131:139 Chgd: 2015-03-02 08:32:46.122363558 -0500 = 1425303166 ‘/var/log/couchdb’
=750,drwxr-x--- 128:4 Chgd: 2015-03-02 08:33:02.030331682 -0500 = 1425303182 ‘/var/log/privoxy’
=750,drwxr-x--- 146:4 Chgd: 2015-03-02 08:33:03.322329094 -0500 = 1425303183 ‘/var/log/tomcat7’
=710,drwx--x--- 0:7 Chgd: 2015-03-04 07:53:31.955392233 -0500 = 1425473611 ‘/var/spool/cups’
```

The entry that seems most involved with logging in and setting up my display is:

```
=700,drwx------ 154:161 Chgd: 2015-02-24 16:06:58.612884945 -0500 = 1424812018 ‘/var/run/gdm/greeter’
```

After I did `sudo chmod 755 /var/run/gdm /var/run/gdm/greeter` I fixed the problem, and can now log in normally.

I will file a bug report.

But, while the above hack fixed the problem once, it reoccurs. NOT SOLVED! I will have to investigate (in `/var/cache/apt/archives`) to see what got installed around `2015-02-24`